# how to create user using admin token

Tags: reactjs, django

i was trying to create user using admin token but the console show me unauthorized when i try to create the user the back-end is Django the front-end is react.js .... only admin can create the user

```
 const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    try {
      console.log("here",values)
      // Make a POST request to the backend API endpoint
        // Get the admin token from localStorage
    const adminToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log(adminToken)

    // Check if the admin token exists
    if (!adminToken) {
      console.log("Admin token not found.");
      // Optionally, you can show an error message or handle the absence of the token
      return;
    }

    // Include the admin token in the request headers
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${adminToken}`,
      },
    };
      const response = await axios.post("http://128.140.431.171:21000/users/", values,config);
      
      // Check if the request was successful
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log("Driver registration successful!");
        // Optionally, you can show a success message or redirect the user to another page
      } else {
        console.log("Driver registration failed.");
        // Optionally, you can show an error message or handle the error in another way
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("An error occurred while registering the driver:", error);
      // Optionally, you can show an error message or handle the error in another way
    }
  };
```

Comment: Could you please share the error message here whatever you're getting?

Comment: [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 272ms]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.